# How to change hover color css button

Tags: html, css, colors, hover

I'm setting up a web and I want to change CSS color on a button.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/usb8l3kpvnpoom8/bandicam%202018-10-15%2023-13-01-381.mp4?dl=0

If you see that video, when mouse is outside the circle the button color is gray. I want to set up this color with blue instead, and when mouse is on the circle, stay the orange color. Hope you have an idea

Comment: This is the web http://chikabika.es/contacto/

Comment: *darna-icon-box.style4 .ibox-icon { color: blue; }*

Answer (score 1):

Hope you could provide the css code next time!

But based on your code from the site, you could change the background color

```
.darna-icon-box.style4 .ibox-icon {
   background-color: blue; // change to hex value if you want
}
```

Add this for hover

```
.darna-icon-box.style4 .ibox-icon:hover {
   background-color: orange; // change to hex value if you want
}
```

Check https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp for more about styling buttons.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can use this format for changing the hover CSS background color

```css
 .your-class:hover {
   background-color: #777 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could set up tags and span things accordingly:

```css
.buttoncolor { background-color: blue; }
.textcolor:hover { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<button class="buttoncolor">
  <a href="path/to/url" class="textcolor">some text</a>
</button>
```